# How can I list images and videos which in external storage?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to list images and videos which in external storage. My codes is:

```
private void parseAllImages() {
    try {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        @SuppressLint("Recycle")
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[]{"%/DCIM/Camera%"},
                null);

        int size = 0;
        if (cursor != null) {
            size = cursor.getCount();
        }

        if (size == 0) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.data_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int file_ColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                String path = cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex);
                String fileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length());
                MediaInfoModel mediaFileInfo = new MediaInfoModel();
                mediaFileInfo.setFilePath(path);
                mediaFileInfo.setFileName(fileName);
                mediaFileInfo.setFileType(type);
                mediaList.add(mediaFileInfo);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can list videos or images with this code. But I don't know how I can list images and videos together. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set multiple types, extend your mediaList to support multiple file formats, and assign different layouts depending on the type.

eg:

```
switch(mediaList.get(index).getType){
    case VIDEO:
          //show video layout
       break;
    case IMAGE:
          //show image layout
       break;
    case OTHER:
          //show other layout
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change query url to `MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")`. This url includes all files, but you can filter data with MediaType. 
You could filter it by adding `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + " = ? OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + " = ? "` to the selection parameter.

Comment: Thank you body. This helps me.